# How to convert column value(ex. "aa,bb,cc") seperated by comma to name (ex."Da,Ba,Ca". -- should refer to other table's column)?

Tags: sql, arrays, mariadb

I use select query to show data in the datagrid.
The problem I am facing is that the select query uses Table_Policy
and as you can see below, some values seperated with comma
and I need to show this model column in grid after convert it to name
For example,

| policy_name | target_name |
| --- | --- |
| Nm22222 | ALL |
| Nm33333 | Double A,Double B,DoubleC |
| Nm44444 | Double C |
| Nm55555 | Double D,Double E |

**Table_Policy**

| ID. | MODEL. |
| --- | --- |
| id22222 | ALL |
| id33333 | AA,BB,CC |
| id44444 | CC |
| id55555 | DD,EE |

**Table_DETAIL**

| CODE. | NAME. |
| --- | --- |
| AA | DOUBLE A |
| BB | DOUBLE B |
| CC | DOUBLE C |
| DD | DOUBLE D |
| EE | DOUBLE E |

Is there a way to make it with query? (MariaDB)
Dev environment is spring boot, jsp, java,MYBATIS
Should I make one more method in MVC?
Please help me with this problem.

I tried first in the javascript ajax.
After ajax success, I used split function to make array
and use this array in the new query

```
select B.Name
from (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
      FROM table_detail
      WHERE CODE IN #{model}
      GROUP BY CODE )B
```

With above query, I get result likt "Double A,Double B,DoubleC"
but I don't know how to use this query to convert the whole column.

Comment: Structure (the S in SQL) your data with a single value per column it falls out very easily. Duplicate the left side column for each individual value on the right hand side. After that its a simple join. If you want the aggregated results as some stage there's `[group_concat](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/).

Comment: Thank you for reponse but I did not get it completely. I guess I have to study more

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
SELECT
 tp.ID,
 tp.MODEL,
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(td.NAME SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Table_DETAIL td WHERE td.CODE IN(tp.MODEL) ) AS NAME
FROM 
  Table_Policy tp
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work. there is a reason why I used alias. To get data list in one value horizontally.  I succeeeded in making it in array type and I don't know how to proceed it with. "aa,bb,vv" ----> "aa","bb","cc"